# Batch - Convert hostname to IP

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, dns, cmd, sccm

This is probably an easy one but I couldn't find the answer and I haven't really done (obviously) much batch programming recently. All I want is to convert an hostname to its IP in a batch file.

Here is my script:

```
set /p ip="IP: " %=%
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CtrlDistance SCCM\cmRcViewer.exe" %ip% \\sccm 
exit
```

Nothing really fancy, this .bat file just starts SCCM after the user entered the IP. However, SCCM in command line doesn't accept hostnames as a paramater, that's why I would like to automatically convert *%ip%* before sending it to the application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example with localhost (not sure about ipv6 output):

```
@echo off
setlocal
    set "ipadr="
    ping -n 1 localhost 2>nul 1>&2 && (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%h in ('ping -n 1 localhost') do (
            set "ipadr=%%h"
            goto :break_loop
        )
    )
    :break_loop
    if defined ipadr ( 
        echo %ipadr% 
        rem you can start SCCM here
    ) else (
        echo host does not exist
    )
endlocal
```

Comment: If the hostname doesn't respond, this is an infinite loop I guess?

Comment: no , `-n 1` switch will cause only one ping request. But you'll get an error message. Additional check of %errorlevel% could be added

Comment: @dnLL - check my "improved" version

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate being able to check if the IP actually pings before starting either SCCM or pcAnywhere (which is the other software we use) since both take a lot of time popping an error in such case. I will give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: It gets the job done after some adaptation, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work however if the full IP has been entered; I just made some modifications so that the `:break_loop` is still inside the `ping` command. If `ipadr` isn't set after the loop but did respond to the original `ping -n 1`, it should mean that the full IP has been used instead of the hostname. I'm just going to post the final code.

Answer (score 1):

Final code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal

if "%1"=="" (
    set /p host="IP: " %=%
) else (
    set host=%1
)

set "ip="
ping -n 1 %host% 2>nul 1>&2 && (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%h in ('ping -n 1 %host%') do (
        set "ip=%%h"
        goto :break_loop
    )
:break_loop
    if not defined ip ( set ip=%host% )
)

if defined ip ( 
    start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CtrlDistance SCCM\cmRcViewer.exe" %ip% \\sccm
) else (
    echo no_ping
    pause
)

endlocal
exit
```